# UnsupportedGeometryTypeError from GML

Tags: python, wfs, geopandas, gml, owslib

I'm trying to download a layer from the WFS service:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

wfs_service = WebFeatureService(url="http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Alluvioni_Estensione.map", version="1.1.0")
response = wfs_service.getfeature(typename="ITH2018_Estensione_HPH")
gml = open('wfs_data.gml', 'wb')
gml.write(bytes(response.read()))
gml.close()
```

I haven't problem to download the GML, but when I try to open that file with GeoPandas using:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('wfs_data.gml', driver='GML', layer='ITH2018_Estensione_HPH')
```

I see the error below:

> ```
> gdf = gpd.read_file('wfs_data.gml', driver='GML', layer='ITH2018_Estensione_HPH')
> ```
>
> /home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/drakonotebook-Mbf4coiv-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py:238:
> in _read_file
> columns = list(features.schema["properties"]) /home/max/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/drakonotebook-Mbf4coiv-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/collection.py:208:
> in schema
> self._schema = self.session.get_schema() fiona/ogrext.pyx:719: in fiona.ogrext.Session.get_schema
> ???
>
> ---
>
> ??? E   fiona.errors.UnsupportedGeometryTypeError: 10
>
> fiona/_geometry.pyx:81: UnsupportedGeometryTypeError

It is the first time that I use a GML file, what I wrong?

When I open the GML file with QGIS I see that the data are rotated and traslated respect of WFS.
[image]

**EDIT**

I tried with a WFS from my own Geoserver:

```
wfs_service = WebFeatureService(url="https://geoserver.massimilianomoraca.me/geoserver/MassimilianoMoraca/wfs", version="2.0.0")
response = wfs_service.getfeature(typename="MassimilianoMoraca:attentionpoints")
```

I can open the GML with GeoPandas without problem.
It is possible that the problem came from the WFS service?

Comment: Are you comparing the same GML formats between services.  What if you call the version 1.1.0 of your own service

Comment: The GML response from the remote WFS is schema valid, and coordinates are in Lat, Long order, which is correct for EPSG:4326

Comment: Excuseme for late response @nmtoken . Using version 1.1.0 I can be able to see correctly  `attentionpoints`.